# HTML parent with 2 child using flexbox but one of them overlap the max-width for parent [ IMG Included ]

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I make this layout with CSS? The parent div is set to max-width 1500px and it is a display flex and a gap 18px with two children #text, #news... news is overlapping to touch the right edge of whatever screen the user has.

[image]

```css
html{
 border:1px solid red;
}
html:after{
content:"HTML";
color:gray;
}
.main{
 display:flex;
 flex-flow:row;
 max-width:350px;
 color:black;
}

.main .child-1 {
 flex: 1 1 40%;
 border:1px solid #000
}

.main .child-2 {
  flex: 1 1 100vw;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.main ul p {
 display:block;
 width 250px; // Whatever
}

ul{
 list-style:none;
 display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <p class="child-1">Some lorem Text</p>
   <div class="child-2">
     <ul>
       <li><p>1</p></li>
       <li><p>2</p></li>
       <li><p>3</p></li>
       <li><p>4</p></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, you’d need html, and to suggest a solution to your problem, we’d need to see your relevant - and **only** the relevant - html that produces the above result. Please, in order for us to help, show your “*[mcve]*” code in your question (as text, not as a picture). Also, read the advice on “*[ask]*.”

Comment: @DavidThomas please re-open it

Comment: you have typos in your CSS (missing `:` character in your `width` declaration, and JavaScript comment (`//`) syntax which is invalid in CSS in the same line,  not to mention at least one missing semi-colon (`;`). Also, having run the (corrected) CSS that code doesn't replicate the problem you show: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1hnfe9kc/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use negative margin to achieve the goal.

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.parent{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
.text{
  width: 25%;
}
.news{
  width:75%;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="news"></div>
</div>
```